# Best-matching sets of individual records into group representatives in c#

Tags: c#

> We're developing a business application using code-first Entity
>   Framework, and I'm looking for a solution to the following problem
>   that stays out of the database if possible.

We have a persistence model that looks similar to the following:

```
public abstract class DataCode
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Option : DataCode
{
   // a bunch of stuff that describes an Option
}

public class Model : DataCode
{
   // a bunch of stuff that describes a product model
}

public class Version
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
   // a bunch of stuff that describes a version of the product model
}

public class ModelOptionVersion
{
   public Model ThisModel { get; set; }
   public Option WithThisOption { get; set; }
   public Version UsingThisVersion { get; set; }
   // a bunch of stuff that is important to track 
   // at the intersection of these three properties
}
```

It all works fine, except that the users want to use "Family Codes" and "Common Codes" to apply property values.  To support that, I think the following classes will work:

```
public abstract class CodeGroup
{
   public virtual ICollection<DataCode> DataCodes { get; set; }
}

public class Family : CodeGroup, DataCode
{
   public Family(ICollection<Model> Models)
   {
      base:DataCodes = Models;
   }
}

public class CommonCode : CodeGroup, DataCode
{
   public Family(ICollection<Option> Options)
   {
      base:DataCodes = Options;
   }
}
```

This is all well and good for expansion of `FamilyCode` and `CommonCode`, along with some logic, into individual `ModelOptionVersion` records (`foreach Model in Family...`).  However, what stumps me is how to best-match a group of `ModelOptionVersion` records *back* into `FamilyCode` or `CommonCode` representatives.

If this were Ford (it's not), the data might look like this:

```
Family    | Model
Trucks    | F-150
Trucks    | F-250
Trucks    | F-350
SuperDuty | F-250
SuperDuty | F-350

CommonCode     | Option
Gas Engines    | 4.6l V-8 Gas
Gas Engines    | 5.4l V-8 Gas
Diesel Engines | 6.4l V-8 Diesel
Diesel Engines | 7.3l V-8 Diesel
Diesel Engines | 6.0l V-8 Diesel

Model | Option          | Version
F-150 | 4.6l V-8 Gas    | 2015
F-150 | 4.6l V-8 Gas    | 2016
F-150 | 5.4l V-8 Gas    | 2015
F-150 | 5.4l V-8 Gas    | 2016
F-250 | 5.4l V-8 Gas    | 2015
F-250 | 5.4l V-8 Gas    | 2016
F-350 | 5.4l V-8 Gas    | 2015
F-350 | 5.4l V-8 Gas    | 2016
F-250 | 6.4l V-8 Diesel | 2015
F-250 | 6.4l V-8 Diesel | 2016
F-350 | 6.4l V-8 Diesel | 2015
F-350 | 6.4l V-8 Diesel | 2016
```

The users want to price things based on "Super Duty with Diesel Engine" or "2016 Truck with Gas Engine".  They not only want to see it that way when they create the price record, but when they go back and look at it later.  So I need a way to not only expand the `FamilyCode` and `DataCode` members, but roll them up.  But it's not necessarily obvious from the data what the source of data was.  Also, the system should be smart enough that when someone says "this is only available on the F-250 and F-350," the system says "use SuperDuty".

It seems to me that I need some sort of best-match solution, perhaps some lightweight fuzzy logic.  Do .NET libraries for this exist?  Do I have to craft it from scratch?  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify "I'm looking for a solution to the following problem that stays out of the database if possible"?  Do you mean that you want to avoid querying the database, or that you want to avoid changing the database by e.g. adding stored procedures, or...?

Comment: My primary goal is to stay on the code side of the EF interface, thereby not adding stored procedures, *et al*.  I presume a certain amount of querying will be necessary, but I'd like to stick to Linq if possible and avoid SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, what stumps me is how to best-match a group of
>   ModelOptionVersion records back into FamilyCode or CommonCode
>   representatives.

What you are trying to do here is to find FamilyCodes (or CommonCodes) such that every ModelOptionVersion in some set has a Model specified by that FamilyCode.

```
var desiredModels = // some collection of Models

var familyCodesByFamily = (
    from familyCode in db.FamilyCodes
    group familyCode by familyCode.Family into family
    select family);

var applicableFamilies = (
    from family in familyCodesByFamily
    where desiredModels.All(dm => family.Any(f=> f.Model == dm))
    select family.Key).ToList();
```

I haven't measured how that kind of query performs, but it doesn't map very directly to what SQL can do.  SQL doesn't directly let you do universal quantifiers ("give me the x such that for all x, y"), but it does let you do existential quantifiers ("give me the x such that there exists a y") and negation.  If it turns out that the above doesn't perform well, an alternative formulation that should be semantically equivalent is:

```
var incorrectFamilies = 
    (from familyCode in db.FamilyCodes
    where !desiredModels.Contains(familyCode.Model)
    select familyCode.Family).Distinct();

var correctFamilies =
    (from familyCode in db.FamilyCodes
    where !incorrectFamilies.Contains(familyCode.Model)
    select familyCode.Family).Distinct().ToList();
```

These generate different SQL, with the natural-seeming first alternative giving more convoluted SQL than the second alternative.  Whichever style you choose, the code for CommonCode should follow the same template.

**EDIT: For true fuzzy matching,** let's develop two measures for how good a match is between a set of models and family.  The first (and more important) measure we'll call "coverage", which relates to how many models are included in the family.  The second we'll call "fit", which relates to how many members of the family are included in the set of models (if you have two families, both of which completely contain the desired models, we want the family that has fewer extra models outside our desired set).  We'll order our results by the goodness of the matches, then take the number of results we can handle.

```
var fuzzyFamilies = (
    from family in familyCodesByFamily
    let coverage = desiredModels.Average(dm => family.Any(f => f.Model == dm) ? 1.0 : 0.0)
    let fit = family.Average(f => desiredModels.Contains(f.Model) ? 1.0 : 0.0)
    orderby coverage descending, fit descending
    select family.Key)
    .Take(resultCount)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This looks great presuming I can generate a set of `desiredModels`.  I suppose that, presuming the number of `FamilyCode`s is reasonably limited, I could quickly generate one list of `desiredModels` for each `FamilyCode` I'm going to try to match.

Comment: `desiredModels` can be generated ad-hoc; you could say for any collection of ModelOptionVersions you happen to have `var desiredModels = myModelOptionVersions.Select(mov => mov.Model);` and executing the `applicableFamilies` query will give you back the matching Familys for those MOVs.

Comment: @J.D.Ray Note! The first snippet of LINQ given here was in error.  I have fixed it and added a snippet that handles incomplete matches.